# Can I monitor traffic on my Incoming Dialup connection using Wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, traffic

I am trying to create a RAS server in XP Pro. The idea is to log in to this server via a dialup connection. I have set up a new network connection via the New Connect Wizard in XP - according to [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5034594.html) on techrepublic.

I am sure that the modem and the connection is working, I have tested it.

However, I want to monitor incoming network traffic on this connection. So I thought I would use Wireshark. The problem is that Wireshark does not list this incoming connection on the front page. It lists all my other network connections, ( e.g. my ethernet connection ) but not this one.

Whats the best way to monitor traffic on this connection?

Comment: You may have to dial up before starting wireshark.

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark should be able to capture the traffic on your connection.  I would check the protocol you're using for communication and make sure that Wireshark is monitoring those protocols.  Also, I would make sure that Wireshark is actually capturing traffic on your dial up device.  It sounds like it's currently monitoring your NIC card, not your modem.

Comment: I see. Do you know how I would force Wireshark to monitor the modem, not the NIC card?

Comment: Try taking a look into the Capture menu item on the top menu... I can't remember exactly how to do it but I believe it's in there.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found Microsoft Network Monitor and it has ability to sniff on dialup adapter with Vista or Win7 as OS. Works great!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/PPP#Windows) Wireshark wiki page, you must use Winpcp ***3.1*** to be able to capture traffic on dial up modems.